# Django multiple HTML forms jquery selector

Tags: jquery, html, django, forms

So what I have is some template logic that creates a HTML form for each key from a dictionary I am passing it :

```
{%if students%}

                    {%for data,student in students.iteritems%}

                        <form  onsubmit = "return false;" id="{{forloop.counter}}">
                            {% csrf_token %}

                            <tr>
                            <td>{{student.name}}</td>
                            {%ifequal student.grade ' '%}
                                <td><input type=text  size="1"  id ='Grade'     name='Grade' maxlength="1" /></td>
                                <td><input type=text  size="50" id = 'Feedback' name='Feedback' /></td>

                            {%else%}
                                <td><input type=text  size="1"  id ='Grade' name='Grade' maxlength="1" value = "{{student.grade}}"/></td>
                                <td><input type=text  size="50" id = 'Feedback' name='Feedback' value = "{{student.feedback}}"/></td>

                            {%endifequal%}
                                <td><button type='submit' class="radius button success medium" onclick=submitGrade("{{forloop.counter}}")>Save</button></td>
                                <td><img src="{% static "img/check.png" %}"></td>
                                <td><input type=hidden id = 'email' name = "email" value = "{{student.email}}"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </form>

                    {%endfor%}
                    </form>
            {%endif%}
```

this will create n forms with the id of the first form being 1, the second being 2, . . ., the nth one being n. Now when I open up the javascript console in chrome and I try to execute `$('#1')` for example, what it returns is `[<form onsubmit=​"return false;​" id=​"1">​</form>​]`. For some reason, the `<input>` is not being associated with the forms. When I try to run `$('#Grade')` from the javascript console, it show `[<input type=​"text" size=​"1" id=​"Grade" name=​"Grade" maxlength=​"1" value=​"A">​]` which is what I expect to be rendered for the Grade input of the first form. Why are the input fields not being associated with their respective form?

Answer (score 0):

ID's are supposed to be unique. It looks like you didn't use the `forloop.counter` in your `<input>` ids. This means that your `for` loop is copying the `id="Grade"` and `id="feedback"` as every form's input ID. Also, selecting ID's with JQuery only manipulates the first instance of the ID tha is found, unless it is captured via `.find()` - i.e. `$('#form1').find('input[id="1"]')`

Example:

`<td><input type=text  size="1"  id ='Grade'     name='Grade' maxlength="1" /></td>`

should be:

`<td><input type=text  size="1"  id ='Grade{{forloop.counter}}'     name='Grade' maxlength="1" /></td>`

and the same goes for `id="feedback"`

////////

Also, it is probably a little better to used named ids, for example:

`<form  onsubmit = "return false;" id="{{forloop.counter}}">`

would be better suited as:

`<form  onsubmit = "return false;" id="form{{forloop.counter}}">`

so the id would be captured by writing `$('#form1')` or `$('#form2')` or etc...

Comment: Hey, I did what you asked, but it doesn't fix the issue. I'm thinking that for some reason the template tags are messing with the jquery

Comment: Did you try: `$('#2').find('#Grade')` (using your code) or `$('#form2').find('#grade2')` (using my code)?

Comment: yep,  `$('#form2').find('#grade2')` return []

Comment: Did you put the `forloop.counter` in both the `if` and the `else` statement input IDs?

Comment: also, it looks like you have an extra `</form>` tag at the end of your html file - delete that if there is no opening tag.

Comment: Yea I did both of them